# DLookup with Both Expression and Criteria are input from form

Tags: ms-access

I am new to Access and VBA. I am currently using Access 365.

I have a table [torque] with the field **[different bolt size]** and fields for each material with required torque.

Currently, I am creating a form where the user select the bolt size and material from ComboBox and generate the required torque value in TextBox.

Hence, I have made a button with the command

```
Required Torque = DLookup([material selection], "torque", [bolt size] = [bolt size selection])
```

With this code, the result returned is always first bolt size in the table no matter what my [bolt size selection] is.

I have experimented by fixing the material (alloy steel)

```
 Required Torque = DLookup([alloy steel], "torque", [bolt size] = [bolt size selection])
```

By fixing the column, the result is returned according to different bolt sizes.

It seems to that the Dlookup function can only take in one variable from form?

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field name to return value from is normally static and there could be multiple criteria. If the fields are text type, use apostrophe delimiters for the parameters.

`Required Torque = DLookup("[required torque]", "torque", "[bolt size] = '" & [bolt size selection] & "' AND [different material]='" & [material selection] & "'")`

A better approach would be a multi-column combobox that has the [required torque] field in one column. Then expression in textbox ControlSource can reference combobox column by index. Index begins with 0 so if the torque is in column 3, index is 2:
`=[comboboxname].Column(2)`.

Then [Torque] table should have a unique identifier key. This key should be saved into data table as foreign key so the required torque value does not have to be saved into data table.

However, if you instead have a column for each material's torque, which is not a normalized structure, the expression would be:

`Required Torque = DLookup("[" & [material selection] & "], "torque", "[bolt size] = '" & [bolt size selection] & "'")`

This assumes the [material selection] combobox lists the field names exactly as they are in the table. Since you use spaces in field names, `[ ]` are required.

Comment: Sorry, there was some autocorrect mistakes in the original post. 

I have a table [torque] with the columns named different materials (alloy steel, stainless steel etc) and each row represents different bolt size. The value in the table is [required torque] for respective material and bolt size.

Comment: See revised answer.