# Filtered Dropdown List of Column Headers based on Row Input in Forms

Tags: ms-access

I am new to Access and still learning.

My task is to create a form where user input the [Bolt Size] and [Tool x] to obtain the data shown in the table (link below).

However, as some of the tool is not available for some bolt sizes, you can see that some of the cells are null.

Therefore, to go one step further for my task, after choosing the bolt size, the user can only see "suitable tool" which is corresponding column header of the cells that is not null based on the bolt size.

For now, I am creating a textbox with DLookup function as the source. However, to do the 'filter dropdown list' for tool based on the bolt size selected in the form, should I use SQL in the source for that combobox?

Please advise. Thank you.

[image: Snapshot of table]

Comment: Normalize table structure. Fields: BoltSize, ToolID, Data. What is this data? Certainly SQL (or a query name) as RowSource, what else would you use? VBA code that builds a ValueList?

Comment: You will need SQL as your `rowsource` and VBA bound to your `Bolt Size` control after update event to fire a `requery` on the `Tool x` control. However as mentioned by June7, you will be much better served if you normalize your data.

Comment: I knew this data looked familiar. Wasn't this already resolved? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52884633/dlookup-with-both-expression-and-criteria-are-input-from-form/52884855#52884855.

Comment: The task is slightly different. I need to create a dropdown list to list out available tool (non-null cell) when user input bolt size. After that, I will do a Dlookup to return the value. Actually, the task is slightly more complicated because i got a list of tables (different properties). Therefore, the table is arranged this way.

Comment: For now I am able to perform the task. However, what I did is hard code the SQL into my row source. (e.g. SELECT "Tool 1" FROM "QUERY' WHERE [TOOL 1] IS NULL union etc). I am ok with the result now but I am imagining situation where I have a huge number of columns. Is there anyway to automate this? Using recordset?